# On the definition of sheaf on a site "without matching families"

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

I'm reading Mac Lane & Moerdijk's *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* and I got stuck at the definition of sheaves on a site.

The authors declare that a presheaf $ F $ on a site $ (\mathcal C,J) $ is a sheaf if for every $ C\in \mathcal C $, for every covering sieve $ S\in J(C) $, and for every family $ (x_f)_{D\xrightarrow{f} C\in S} $ of sections $ x_f\in F(D) $ such that $ x_f\cdot g = x_{f\circ g} $ for every arrow $ g\colon E\to D $, there exists a unique section $ x\in F(C) $ such that $ x\cdot f = x_f $ for each $ f\in S $. Here of course $ x_f\cdot g $ means $ F(g)(x_f) $.

Some lines below it is claimed that the above definition could be restated as follows: $ F $ is a sheaf if and only if for each $ C\in\mathcal C $ and for any covering sieve $ S\in J(C) $, the obvious mapping
$$
\hom(h_C,F)\to \hom(S,F)
$$
where $ h_C = \hom({-},C) $ and the sieve $ S $ is interpreted in an obvious way as a subfunctor of $ h_C $, is an isomorphism.

I couldn't convince myself that what the book is saying is correct. The isomorphism condition above states that given a matching family $ (x_f)_{f\in S} $, there is a matching family $ (y_t)_{t\in S_C} $ *defined with respect to the maximal covering sheaf $ S_C $ on $ C $*, such that $ y_f = x_f $ for $ f\in S $. But shouldn't sheaves be meant to give a "global" thing starting from a bunch of "local" things, and not another bunch of "local" things, as it seems to be a morphism of presheaves $ h_C\to F $?

Comment: A morphism $h_C \to F$ has no difference with an element of $F(C)$ (Yoneda). <insert "they are the same picture" meme>

Comment: surprised_pikachu.jpg (that's actually an answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: A meme format where a woman is shown two pictures, subtitled "Corporate needs you to find the differences between this picture and this picture". The woman responds "they are the same picture". Here the two pictures are the two mathematical objects stated to be isomorphic by the Yoneda lemma.]

The Yoneda lemma states that
$$\hom(よ(C), F) \cong F(C)$$
where $よ(C) = \hom(-, C)$ is the Yoneda embedding. Therefore the morphism of presheaves $よ(C) \to F$ already gives us the global thing.

Comment: ($\cong$… naturally in both $C$ and $F$)